# Why isn't lldb setting my breakpoint correctly?

Tags: macos, lldb

I've got a chunk of some assembly and am assembling it on osx like this:

```
as -g -o tallest.o tallest.s
ld --static -o tallest tallest.o
```

I fire up lldb, set a breakpoint at line 57 in tallest.s and check the info on the set breakpoint.  The info is wrong.

```
chris@goldfish chapter07 % lldb tallest              
(lldb) target create "tallest"
Current executable set to '/Users/chris/Dev/assembly/learning-assembly/chapter07/tallest' (x86_64).
(lldb) break set -f tallest.s -l 57
Breakpoint 1: where = tallest`endloop, address = 0x0000000100003fa9
(lldb) break list 1 --verbose
1: file = 'tallest.s', line = 57, exact_match = 0
    1.1: 
      module = /Users/chris/Dev/assembly/learning-assembly/chapter07/tallest
      compile unit = tallest.s
      location = /Users/chris/Dev/assembly/learning-assembly/chapter07/tallest.s:64
      address = tallest[0x0000000100003fa9]
      resolved = false
      hardware = false
      hit count = 0   


(lldb)
```

Notice that the break point is set at line 64, not line 57 as requested.  This isn't always broken.  Here's an example from the same debug session that works on line 54:

```
(lldb) break set -f tallest.s -l 54
Breakpoint 2: where = tallest`mainloop, address = 0x0000000100003f99
(lldb) break list 2 --verbose
2: file = 'tallest.s', line = 54, exact_match = 0
    2.1: 
      module = /Users/chris/Dev/assembly/learning-assembly/chapter07/tallest
      compile unit = tallest.s
      location = /Users/chris/Dev/assembly/learning-assembly/chapter07/tallest.s:54
      address = tallest[0x0000000100003f99]
      resolved = false
      hardware = false
      hit count = 0   


(lldb)
```

Running the code, lldb stops at lines 54 and 64.  If I try to step from 54 to 57, it shows me this on stopping:

```
(lldb) n
Process 59180 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003f9d tallest`mainloop + 4
tallest`mainloop:
->  0x100003f9d <+4>:  cmpq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100003fa0 <+7>:  jge    0x100003fa9               ; endloop
    0x100003fa6 <+13>: movq   %rax, %rdi

tallest`endloop:
    0x100003fa9 <+0>:  addq   $0x28, %rbx
Target 0: (tallest) stopped.
(lldb)
```

That's not my assembly code from `tallest.s`.  I expect it is just what lldb disassembled.  The question would be what can I do to my code or build process to make it more likely that lldb can list my code when it stops at a breakpoint?

Based on Jim Ingham's comment, I ran the lldb source info -f tallest.s command which listed only some of my source lines.  For example lines 57, 58, and 61 are missing from the output.

Comment: lldb only knows what the compiler generated "line table" tells it.  You can dump this with the `source info -f my_file.s` command.  That might help you make sense of the behavior.  It looks likely that your source mapping has some holes...  Those could be compiler bugs. or it just did some complex transformation (particularly like if the optimizer is on) and there isn't a good mapping for some part of that code.

Comment: Also remember that if there is no "line entry" at a particular source line, lldb will move it to the next higher line with source info.  That's why you end up getting a different line number in the location from the one you requested in your breakpoint command.  You can turn this off by passing `--move-to-nearest-code 0` as part of the `break set` command.

Comment: @JimIngham, Based on the results of the `source info` command, I see that a number of lines are not included.  Is there something I can do to the source, or during assembly that will get a more complete debug info?

Comment: Pretty much the only control you have over this is the optimization level.  The higher the optimization level the more difficulty the compiler has mapping instructions back to source lines.